# .animate and .offset doesn't work in jQuery script

Tags: jquery

I'm using this little jQuery script:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top-128
  }, 500);
});
```

with jQuery v. 3.5.1. jQuery is ofc working properly, because I have others working scripts. Console is empty, no errors. My script should animate scrolling to anchor with offset from top. What's wrong whit this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to scroll to the parent of the clicked link. You have to get the `href` from the clicked link and scroll to the element with that id.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top-128
    }, 500);
});
```

You can see it working here:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top-128
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
.bigblock {height:500px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<a href="#div1">go to 1</a> <a href="#div2">go to 2</a> <a href="#div3">go to 3</a>
<div class="bigblock" id = "div1">Block 1</div>
<div class="bigblock" id = "div2">Block 2</div>
<div class="bigblock" id = "div3">Block 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh, your'e right... I paste wrong script in my post, because I was trying other proposed method, and I missed it. But with '$( $.attr(this, 'href') )' also doesn't work :( I just edited my post. Problem still exist.

Comment: @DamianP. I have added an example to my answer that you can see it working.

Comment: Now I understand! Href should be starts from "#"! If I have https://sally.agency/kontakt/#wycena like on my site it won't work. :)

Comment: Ok, one more, last question: I have link like this: 'https://sally.agency/kontakt/#wycena' this link is on every subpage and redirects to specific div#wycena in "kontakt" page. How can I create offset from top with this link, for this div, but with no CSS paddings / margins?

Comment: @Damian that is a different answer so you have to post another question for it :). Questions on StackOverflow are only supposed to have one at a time. If you post another question I can answer or someone else might give you an answer. Sorry its just the way it works here.